# Create Batch Apex to update multiple objects

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, salesforce-communities

I already have a Schedule apex, that works on 3 objects to do a basic Query and update. I wanted to make this class batch. But unable to add multiple objects in Batch apex and loop around them .

Here is how my Schedule apex looks like

```
`global class scheduleWorkday implements Schedulable {

 global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {

  //Get Accounts

        List<Account> getbdayaccount = [Select ID, Name, Address from Account where State= CT];

        if(!getbdayaccount .isEmpty()) {
                for(Account a : getbdayaccount ) {
                a.name = 'Test';
                a.State= 'NJ';
            }
            update getbdayaccount ;
        }

//get Leads 

   List<Lead> getPreApprovalFollow = [Select ID, Name, State, LeadSource from Lead where State = 'CT' ];

        if(!getPreApprovalFollow .isEmpty()) {
               for(Lead l: getPreApprovalFollow ) {
                l.LeadSource = 'Referral';
                l.State = 'NJ';
            }
            update getPreApprovalFollow ;
        }

//get Opportunities 

List<Opportunity> getopps = [Select Id, CloseDate, State from Lead where State = 'CT'];

   if(!getopps.isEmpty()){
     for(Opportunity o : getopps){
     o.CloseDate = Date.Today();
      o.State = 'CT';
}
update get opps;


}



}


}`
```

I  tried making batch apex something like this -

```
global class LeadProcessor implements Database.Batchable <SObject> {
//START METHOD
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        String Query='Select id,LeadSource, State from Lead where state = 'CT';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(Query);
            }
//EXECUTE METHOD
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Lead> scope){
        for(Lead l: scope){
            l.LeadSource='Referral';
            l.State = 'NJ';

        }
        update scope;
    }
//FINISH METHOD
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){

    }
}
```

How can I change this batch apex to return multiple queries, add a loop  and update them .

Answer (score 1):

That's not how Batch Apex works. You can iterate over exactly one query in a Batch Apex job.

Because you are mutating three different objects in three different ways, the options of batch chaining and use of Dynamic SOQL don't really apply here. You'll simply need to build three different batch classes.

You can run these classes in parallel, or have each one chain into the next in its `finish()` method. But you can't do it all in one batch.